# What is a selfish Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what%20is%20a%22%20word%20is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What%20is%20%22%20%22Word%22%20-missing%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **selfish** word.
Here is a list of selfish and not-selfish words:

| SELFISH | NOT SELFISH |
| --- | --- |
| noun | adjective |
| short | long |
| prefixed | uncomplicated |
| common | uncommon |
| pedantic | imprecise |
| erudite | uncultured |
| word | sentence |
| polysyllabic | monosyllabic |
| TLA | SLA |
| writable | unwritable |

Here is a CSV version for copy-paste purpose:

```
SELFISH;NOT SELFISH
noun;adjective
short;long
prefixed;uncomplicated
common;uncommon
pedantic;imprecise
erudite;uncultured
word;sentence
polysyllabic;monosyllabic
TLA;SLA
writable;unwritable
```

**QUESTION:** What is the rule to tell whether a word is a **selfish** word or not?

Credits: my nerdy colleague. Dedicated to a friend of mine who thinks I only know mathematical and logical puzzles.

Hint:

> "selfish" and "mispeled" are two selfish words

Comment: Just noticed you used the word "not-selfish" there; which list would you place that word on? :-)

Comment: @Bass lol I think it is related to the set-not-containing-itself paradox

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> A selfish word is one that is autological; that is, a word that describes itself.
>
> For example, "word" is a word, "polysyllabic" is has multiple syllables, and "prefixed" contains the prefix "pre". The one that's the least obvious to me is the word "pedantic" but i guess you could say that a word describing a subject relates to it?

Comment: I'm not an English native speaker, maybe I could have written rot13(Cbzcbhf vafgrnq bs crqnagvp)